# How to get last SVN access date

Tags: logging, svn, version-control, monitoring

I need to get when was the last checkout for a SVN repository but there is no command or way to get this information directly.

I can get when the last modification  was  but not the last "access" date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run a Subversion server that has [high-level logging](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/operational-logging/) and also [Apache logging](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging) enabled. For example, events with the keyword `checkout-or-export` mean that a user exported repository contents or checked out a working copy. [Read SVNBook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/)! :)